# Can I use Prism with Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android (not Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, prism

Currently I start to build a UI with Xamarin.Forms and Prism.Forms using MVVM. But I would like to keep the opportunity to switch from Xamarin.Forms back to Xamarim.iOS and Xamarin.Android if Xamarin.Forms does not fit my requirements. But I'm not sure if Prism is also usable when I'm not using Xamarin.Forms? If it is usable, how much effort is it to switch the UI from Xamarin.Forms to Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android? Or are there better MVVM Frameworks out there to support theses UI switch which causes less efforts?

Thanks for answers

Karin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You can only use the Prism.Core NuGet package in native Xamarin apps which contains commands and event aggregation.  The Prism.Forms package will only work for Xamarin.Forms.